# GitHub: Can't upload or commit powershell scripts

Tags: github, upload, commit

I'm facing an issue on GitHub when trying to upload or commit powershell scripts (.PS1 files). When changing the format to .TXT, the same issue appears with the following message:

```
Something went really wrong, and we can’t process that file.
```

Tried to use different computers in different networks, clear cache, format the code/text, or search for script configurations that may be blocking the upload. But still having the same problem.

How can I solve this?